# Firebase Crashlytics - is it installed correctly?

Tags: xcode, firebase

I have moved over to Firebase in my XCode app and followed the instructions for the installation. There are no error messages and the Analytics seem to be working as I am getting some data showing in the Analytics Dashboard but I am not getting any information in the Crashlytics section even through I have forced a few crashes.

When I run the app in XCode I get the following line in the console:

> [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.1.0

So it would seem something is working. The only thing I am uncertain of is the exact entries in the Run Script section and I am imagine the error is there. This is probably a very basic question but I assume I have to replace some of the entries to suit my project/computer.

Any direction here would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: did you upload the dsyms to Firebase?

Comment: Is that not meant to be automatic?

Comment: No, you should do that for each build that you want Crashlythics from. More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=0

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem. I had to stop the run from XCode and then start it from the simulator so that it is running from outside XCode. Obvious really as we would end up having so many crash reports as we debug.

Comment: Glad you sorted that out : )